# Find the lower peaks of the list

Tags: prolog

Help, please, find the lower peaks of the list. For example, given an array `[1,5,4,6,3]` the answer would be `[1,4,3]`

```
lower_peaks([X,Y|T],[X|L]):-X<Y,lp2([Y|T],L).
lower_peaks([X,Y|T],L):-lp2([X,Y|T],L).

lp2([X,Y],[Y]):-Y<X.
lp2([_,_],[]).
lp2([X,Y,Z|T],[Y|L]):-Y<X,Y<Z,lp2([Y,Z|T],L).
lp2([X,Y,Z|T],L):-lp2([Y,Z|T],L).
```

The problem is multiple answers:

```
?- lower_peaks([1,5,4,6,3],V).
V = [1, 4, 3] ;
V = [1, 4] ;
V = [1, 3] ;
V = [1] ;
V = [4, 3] ;
V = [4] ;
V = [3] ;
V = [] ;
false.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Complete code:

```
lower_peaks(L,R) :-
    lower_peaks_start(L,R).

lower_peaks([_],[]).

lower_peaks([],[]).

lower_peaks_start([X,Y|T],[X|L]) :-
    X<Y,
    lower_peaks_middle([Y|T],L).
lower_peaks_start([X,Y|T],L) :-
    \+ (X<Y),
    lower_peaks_middle([Y|T],L).

lower_peaks_middle([X,Y,Z|T],[Y|L]) :-
    Y<X, Y<Z,
    lower_peaks_middle([Y,Z|T],L).
lower_peaks_middle([X,Y,Z|T],L) :-
    \+ (Y<X, Y<Z),
    lower_peaks_middle([Y,Z|T],L).

lower_peaks_middle([X,Y],L) :-
    lower_peaks_end([X,Y],L).

lower_peaks_end([X,Y],[Y]) :-
    Y<X.
lower_peaks_end([X,Y],[]) :-
    \+ (Y<X).
```

Example run:

```
?- lower_peaks([1,5,4,6,3],V).
V = [1, 4, 3] ;
false.
```

There were several problems with the code.

1. The code had guards, e.g. `X<Y` for the one predicate, but either a cut (!) or better a not guard `\+ (X<Y)` for the matching predicate was needed.
2. The code transitioned from the start of the list to the middle, e.g. `lower_peaks` then to `lp2` but did not transition for the end.
3. The code needed base cases for a list of one or no items.
4. The code needed a way to transition from the start of list to the end of  list if there was no middle.